# Is there a best practice for using DRY with several partially overlapping logic streams?

Tags: if-statement

I was unsure how to search for this, so if it has been answered, please point me to it.

I have once again come upon a fairly common situation in which I am unsure of the best practice. Consider a situation in which a function has one of three possible values; we will say they are 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

If I receive 'a' or 'b', I have a a significant amount of overlapping processing to do, after some case specific stuff. However, if I receive 'c', I need to do something completely different. This is trivial for the sake of example, but I have some across some pretty heavy instances of this.

Example (Python):

```py
def doStuff(self, val):
    if   val == 'a':
        self.counter += 1
        print val, "is very good"
        self.passing = True
        self.doMoreStuff()
    elif val == 'b':
        self.counter += 2
        print val, "is not too bad"
        self.passing = True
        self.doMoreStuff()
    elif val == 'c':
        self.counter -= 1
        self.passing = False
        print val, "is unacceptable"
        self.weAreDoneHere()
```

So the idea is that for either 'a' or 'b', there are some case-specific instructions and some repeated stuff, but for 'c', it's all different. In some cases, it's not too bad to just leave the three separate cases, though it makes my DRY eye twitch to look at it. In other cases, if there's a lot of repeated code, it can be a bigger problem.

One solution would be something like the following:

```py
def doStuff(self, val):
    if   val == 'a' or val == 'b':
        if val == 'a':
            self.counter += 1
            print val, "is very good"
        elif val == 'b':
            self.counter += 2
            print val, "is not too bad"
        self.passing = True
        self.doMoreStuff()
    elif val == 'c':
        self.counter -= 1
        self.passing = False
        print val, "is unacceptable"
        self.weAreDoneHere()
```

Is this double-checking-the-value method okay? It also makes my DRY eye twitch a little, but not as much as repeating huge blocks of code.

My real question, I suppose, is **has this been discussed somewhere or is there a standard "best practice" way to do this?**

Comment: I don't know python, but in most cases you would refactor everything common between A and B and put them in a private function, then call that from A and B.

Comment: python is less important, it was a pretty arbitrary choice. What about the case where the common code isn't really enough to warrant an additional method, only 3 or 4 lines?

Comment: I think most people would argue that even one common line is enough to warrant a new **private** function.

Comment: I can go with that. Though I would argue the "one common line is enough" point, since it would cost you one common line to call the function. Two lines, though? Done.

Comment: Also, if you toss your comments into an answer I'll give you an accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know python, but in most cases you would refactor everything common between A and B and put them in a private function, then call that from A and B.

An example in javascript:

```
var someFunction = function (someArg) {
    var stuffCommonToAandB = function () {
        // stuff for both A and B
    };

    switch (true) {
        case someArg === 'A':
            stuffCommonToAandB();
            // stuff for A only
            break;
        case someArg === 'B':
            stuffCommonToAandB();
            // stuff for B only
            break;
        case someArg === 'C':
            // stuff for C only
            break;
    }
};
```

It might be worth mentioning that passing flags like this to a function to toggle different behaviors can sometimes be a sign that your function is violating the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), in which case you would want to take a step back and rethink your design further.